# Перестает работать свойство flex-grow по ширине для контейнера после выравнивания родительского блока

Tags: css, flexbox

элементы с классом `.block` должны занимать по ширине все свободное пространство. И это работает пока я не выравниваю родительский `.container` по центру свойством `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
@import "normalize.css";

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: springgreen;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Проблема с шириной после этого свойства */
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="block">1</div>
      <div class="block center">2</div>
      <div class="block">3</div>
    </div>

    <footer>gsdsdg</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: max-width замените на width

Comment: Но тогда блок container перестанет быть резиновым

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import "normalize.css";
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: springgreen;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  /* Просто заставьте его пытаться занять доступное пространство */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Проблема с шириной после этого свойства */
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: slateblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="block">1</div>
      <div class="block center">2</div>
      <div class="block">3</div>
    </div>

    <footer>gsdsdg</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```